# EXT 4.2 ComboBox grouping of results with XTemplate

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, grouping, extjs4.2

I am trying to group results that I am getting from store to be displayed inside ComboBox . 
I have a combobox that looks like this: 
[image]

and I need it to look like this :

[image]

That means grouped by category (order / invoice ).

My combobox defined like this :

```
Ext.define('NG.view.searchcombo.Combo', {
    requires: ['Ext.form.field.ComboBox'],
    extend: 'Ext.form.ComboBox',
    alias: 'widget.searchcombo',
    minChars:3,
    fieldLabel: 'Choose Search',
    store: 'Search',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'id',
    typeAhead: false,
    hideLabel: true,
    hideTrigger:false,
    anchor: '100%',

    listConfig: {
        loadingText: 'Searching...',
        emptyText: 'No matching posts found.',

        // Custom rendering template for each item
        getInnerTpl: function() {
            return '<h3>{name} / {category}</h3>' +'{excerpt}' ;
        }
    },
    pageSize: 10,
    initComponent: function () {    

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

and my data is like this :

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "one",
    "category": "invoice"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "two",
    "category": "invoice"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "one",
    "category": "order"
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "two",
    "category": "order"
}, {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "three",
    "category": "invoice"
}, {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "four",
    "category": "invoice"
}, {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "three",
    "category": "order"
}, {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "four",
    "category": "order"
}, {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "five",
    "category": "invoice"
}, {
    "id": 10,
    "name": "six",
    "category": "invoice"
}, {
    "id": 11,
    "name": "five",
    "category": "order"
}, {
    "id": 12,
    "name": "six",
    "category": "order"
}, {
    "id": 13,
    "name": "seven",
    "category": "invoice"
}, {
    "id": 14,
    "name": "eight",
    "category": "invoice"
}, {
    "id": 15,
    "name": "seven",
    "category": "order"
}, {
    "id": 16,
    "name": "eight",
    "category": "order"
}]
```

I think that can be done by using `Ext.XTemplate` but I am not familiar with `Ext.XTemplate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, you can get this done using a Grid to Render your combobox content. Refer to this post: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?132328-CLOSED-ComboBox-using-Grid-instead-of-BoundList

Following the article I was able to create this:

[image]

Answer (score 14):

I wanted a much simpler solution, so I'll share what I came up with.

For my purposes, I had a `key` that I wanted to group on, which is a single character.  I knew the headers I wanted to show for each key, so I pre-sorted the list to make sure the types came together, and then I just render a group header each time I see a new key.

```
myStore.sort('key', 'DESC');

Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
  store: myStore,
  queryMode: 'local',
  displayField: 'name',
  valueField: 'id',
  listConfig: {
    cls: 'grouped-list'
  },
  tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
    '{[this.currentKey = null]}' +
    '<tpl for=".">',
      '<tpl if="this.shouldShowHeader(key)">' +
        '<div class="group-header">{[this.showHeader(values.key)]}</div>' +
      '</tpl>' +
      '<div class="x-boundlist-item">{name}</div>',
    '</tpl>',
    {
      shouldShowHeader: function(key){
        return this.currentKey != key;
      },
      showHeader: function(key){
        this.currentKey = key;
        switch (key) {
          case 's': return 'Structures';
          case 'f': return 'Filters';
          ...
        }
        return 'Other';
      }
    }
  )
});
```

Using the following CSS:

```
.grouped-list .x-boundlist-item {
  padding: 1px 3px 0 10px
}

.grouped-list .group-header {
  padding: 4px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

And this data:

```
[
    { key: 's', name: '2014 Product Development' },
    { key: 'f', name: 'Message Filter' },
    { key: 's', name: '2014 Product Development (Little)' },
    { key: 's', name: 'Global Structure' },
    { key: 'f', name: 'My SW' }
]
```

I get a nice looking grouped list like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you please sample data which you are binding to the combobox. Thanks !!

Comment: the problem with this solution is that the code has knowledge about the content of the data. this limits it's usage to a specific data set. Perhaps the data should carry information about the headers, e.g. if a record is in fact a header.

Comment: @TsahiAsher That is true.  This was the solution for my scenario.  It could easily be adapted to a situation where the data included `group` instead of `key`, and then the template would just be updated.

Comment: Thanks ! worked as a charm. But, I am getting "null" as a first header which is additional and not required ! any idea how to avoid it ?
I think it is because of `'{[this.currentKey = null]}' +`

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense that it would output "null", but it must've just been hidden for me. I think you can just remove that initialization line altogether, since whether it is initially null or undefined shouldn't matter.

Comment: @SaurabhBayani you can replace it with `{%this.currentKey = null%}`, so it's added to the template code but not written to the page.

Answer (score 8):

This is an extension that improves on Sean Adkinson answer above by making a reusable component from his code.

I have had mixed results with replacing BoundList with a GridPanel with Ext 5.0.1 there for this is what I used.

One caveat it does not support collapsing the groups but it works great for me.

Tested in Extjs 4.2.3 and 5.0.1.

You can see it in Sencha [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/e5n)

Hope it helps someone out there.

```js
Ext.define('Ext.ux.GroupComboBox', {
  extend: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',
  alias: 'widget.groupcombobox',
  /*
   * @cfg groupField String value of field to groupBy, set this to any field in your model
   */
  groupField: 'group',
  listConfig: {
    cls: 'grouped-list'
  },
  initComponent: function() {
    var me = this;
    me.tpl = new Ext.XTemplate([
      '{%this.currentGroup = null%}',
      '<tpl for=".">',
      '   <tpl if="this.shouldShowHeader(' + me.groupField + ')">',
      '       <div class="group-header">{[this.showHeader(values.' + me.groupField + ')]}</div>',
      '   </tpl>',
      '   <div class="x-boundlist-item">{' + me.displayField + '}</div>',
      '</tpl>', {
        shouldShowHeader: function(group) {
          return this.currentGroup != group;
        },
        showHeader: function(group) {
          this.currentGroup = group;
          return group;
        }
      }
    ]);
    me.callParent(arguments);
  }
});

//Example usage
var Restaurants = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
  storeId: 'restaraunts',
  fields: ['name', 'cuisine'],
  sorters: ['cuisine', 'name'],
  groupField: 'cuisine',
  data: [{
    name: 'Cheesecake Factory',
    cuisine: 'American'
  }, {
    name: 'University Cafe',
    cuisine: 'American'
  }, {
    name: 'Creamery',
    cuisine: 'American'
  }, {
    name: 'Old Pro',
    cuisine: 'American'
  }, {
    name: 'Nola\'s',
    cuisine: 'Cajun'
  }, {
    name: 'House of Bagels',
    cuisine: 'Bagels'
  }, {
    name: 'The Prolific Oven',
    cuisine: 'Sandwiches'
  }, {
    name: 'La Strada',
    cuisine: 'Italian'
  }, {
    name: 'Buca di Beppo',
    cuisine: 'Italian'
  }, {
    name: 'Pasta?',
    cuisine: 'Italian'
  }, {
    name: 'Madame Tam',
    cuisine: 'Asian'
  }, {
    name: 'Sprout Cafe',
    cuisine: 'Salad'
  }, {
    name: 'Pluto\'s',
    cuisine: 'Salad'
  }, {
    name: 'Junoon',
    cuisine: 'Indian'
  }, {
    name: 'Bistro Maxine',
    cuisine: 'French'
  }, {
    name: 'Three Seasons',
    cuisine: 'Vietnamese'
  }, {
    name: 'Sancho\'s Taquira',
    cuisine: 'Mexican'
  }, {
    name: 'Reposado',
    cuisine: 'Mexican'
  }, {
    name: 'Siam Royal',
    cuisine: 'Thai'
  }, {
    name: 'Krung Siam',
    cuisine: 'Thai'
  }, {
    name: 'Thaiphoon',
    cuisine: 'Thai'
  }, {
    name: 'Tamarine',
    cuisine: 'Vietnamese'
  }, {
    name: 'Joya',
    cuisine: 'Tapas'
  }, {
    name: 'Jing Jing',
    cuisine: 'Chinese'
  }, {
    name: 'Patxi\'s Pizza',
    cuisine: 'Pizza'
  }, {
    name: 'Evvia Estiatorio',
    cuisine: 'Mediterranean'
  }, {
    name: 'Gyros-Gyros',
    cuisine: 'Mediterranean'
  }, {
    name: 'Mango Caribbean Cafe',
    cuisine: 'Caribbean'
  }, {
    name: 'Coconuts Caribbean Restaurant &amp; Bar',
    cuisine: 'Caribbean'
  }, {
    name: 'Rose &amp; Crown',
    cuisine: 'English'
  }, {
    name: 'Baklava',
    cuisine: 'Mediterranean'
  }, {
    name: 'Mandarin Gourmet',
    cuisine: 'Chinese'
  }, {
    name: 'Bangkok Cuisine',
    cuisine: 'Thai'
  }, {
    name: 'Darbar Indian Cuisine',
    cuisine: 'Indian'
  }, {
    name: 'Mantra',
    cuisine: 'Indian'
  }, {
    name: 'Janta',
    cuisine: 'Indian'
  }, {
    name: 'Starbucks',
    cuisine: 'Coffee'
  }, {
    name: 'Peet\'s Coffee',
    cuisine: 'Coffee'
  }, {
    name: 'Coupa Cafe',
    cuisine: 'Coffee'
  }, {
    name: 'Lytton Coffee Company',
    cuisine: 'Coffee'
  }, {
    name: 'Il Fornaio',
    cuisine: 'Italian'
  }, {
    name: 'Lavanda',
    cuisine: 'Mediterranean'
  }, {
    name: 'MacArthur Park',
    cuisine: 'American'
  }, {
    name: 'St Michael\'s Alley',
    cuisine: 'Californian'
  }, {
    name: 'Cafe Renzo',
    cuisine: 'Italian'
  }, {
    name: 'Miyake',
    cuisine: 'Sushi'
  }, {
    name: 'Sushi Tomo',
    cuisine: 'Sushi'
  }, {
    name: 'Kanpai',
    cuisine: 'Sushi'
  }, {
    name: 'Pizza My Heart',
    cuisine: 'Pizza'
  }, {
    name: 'New York Pizza',
    cuisine: 'Pizza'
  }, {
    name: 'Loving Hut',
    cuisine: 'Vegan'
  }, {
    name: 'Garden Fresh',
    cuisine: 'Vegan'
  }, {
    name: 'Cafe Epi',
    cuisine: 'French'
  }, {
    name: 'Tai Pan',
    cuisine: 'Chinese'
  }]
});

Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
  items: Ext.create('Ext.ux.GroupComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Restaurants',
    name: 'txtRestaurant',
    forceSelection: true,
    editable: false,
    queryMode: 'local',
    triggerAction: 'all',
    multiSelect: true,
    groupField: 'cuisine',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'name',
    store: Restaurants,
    width: 400
  })
}).show();
```

```css
.grouped-list .x-boundlist-item {
  padding: 1px 3px 0 10px;
}
.grouped-list .group-header {
  padding: 4px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

Comment: I like this one. I fixed a small bug in the template (waiting review), and I would like it better if the template used <ul> instead of <div>.

Comment: Nice extension. Can you help me with the following. When I use it in Ext 5.0.0, the groupFields are doubled each time I type to filter. See this fork on your fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ugi

Comment: This is nice, thanks for cleaning up my solution to be more reusable :+1:

Answer (score 0):

That is the code the worked for me:

If you are using Sencha Architect, add the createPicker inside an Override and manually create the listConfig as an Object.

```
{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    createPicker: function() {
        var me = this,
            picker,
            menuCls = Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'menu',
            opts = Ext.apply({
                selModel: {
                    mode: me.multiSelect ? 'SIMPLE' : 'SINGLE'
                },
                floating: true,
                hidden: true,
                ownerCt: me.ownerCt,
                cls: me.el.up('.' + menuCls) ? menuCls : '',
                store: me.store,
                displayField: me.displayField,
                focusOnToFront: false,
                pageSize: me.pageSize
            }, me.listConfig, me.defaultListConfig);

        // NOTE: we simply use a grid panel
        //picker = me.picker = Ext.create('Ext.view.BoundList', opts);


        picker = me.picker = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', opts);

        // hack: pass getNode() to the view
        picker.getNode = function() {
            picker.getView().getNode(arguments);
        };

        me.mon(picker.getView(), {
            refresh: me.onListRefresh,
            scope: me
        });
        me.mon(picker, {
            itemclick: me.onItemClick,
            //            refresh: me.onListRefresh,
            scope: me
        });

        me.mon(picker.getSelectionModel(), {
            selectionChange: me.onListSelectionChange,
            scope: me
        });

        return picker;
    },
    listConfig: {
        columns: [{
            xtype: "gridcolumn",
            dataIndex: "id",
            text: "Id"
        }, {
            xtype: "gridcolumn",
            dataIndex: "name",
            text: "Name"
        }],
        features: [{
            ftype: "grouping"
        }]
    },
    fieldLabel: 'Label',
    queryMode: 'local',
    store: 'myTestStore'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented my own version of the combo with a grid as its list component. You can get it on [GitHub](https://github.com/rixo/GridPicker), and I've put some [examples online](http://planysphere.fr/ext/GridPicker/examples/).

The 3rd example closely matches what you're trying to achieve.

Here's an example that would match even more closely. You'd only be left with the styling to do:

```
Ext.widget('gridpicker', {

    queryMode: 'local'
    ,displayField: 'name'

    ,store: {
        fields: ['name', 'group']
        ,proxy: {type: 'memory', reader: 'array'}
        ,data: ...
        ,groupField: 'group'
        ,sorters: {property: 'name', order: 'ASC'}
    }

    ,gridConfig: {
        features: [{
            ftype:'grouping'
            ,groupHeaderTpl: '{name}'
            ,collapsible: false
        }]
        ,columns: [{
            width: 30
            ,renderer: function(value, md, record, rowIndex) {
                return '<img src="..." />';
            }
        },{
            dataIndex: 'name'
            ,flex: 1
        }]
    }
});
```